# Signature of the body and declaration in a method implementation do not match. - on master page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I just converted my .net 2.0 application to a .net 3.5 application

- there was an error converting the website project
- so i recreated the website project
- added the website files again (which converted successfully) and got added to the project

No build errors

but on runtime I get this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during
>   the parsing of a resource required to
>   service this     request. Please
>   review the following specific parse
>   error details and modify your source
>   file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Signature of the
>   body and declaration in a method
>   implementation do not match.  Type:
>   'MyMaster'.  Assembly:
>   'CompName.ProjectName,
>   Version=1.2.3631.30873,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
> Line 1:  <%@ Import namespace="System.Diagnostics"%>
> ```
>
> **Line 2:  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="MyMaster" Codebehind="MyMaster.master.cs"  %>**
>
> ```
> Line 3:  <%@ Register Src="Controls/MyControl.ascx" TagName="MyControl"     TagPrefix="mc"%>
> Line 4:
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The underlying error was an Ajax Problem

The new website project was pointing to the new Ajax DLL in the .net entity framework
(System.Extensions)

I had to goto the .proj file in notepad and edit the reference to point to the old .net AJAX DLL.